# prime number digits less than n?

Tags: factorization, digits

How can I ask mathematica to sieve with only primes with three-digit less than a given number. Thank you
for instance I want to find the prime factor of 1337. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

1337 has four digits. You ask for primes with 3 digits less than that.

```
Select[Range[10^(Floor[Log10[1337]]-3),10^(Floor[Log10[1337]]-2)],PrimeQ]
```

gives you

```
{2,3,5,7}
```

which are the primes with 4-3==1 digit.

```
Select[{2,3,5,7},Mod[1337,#]==0&]
```

will use only those primes and sieve to find which of those are factors of 1337 giving you

```
{7}
```

Answer (score 3):

Does the following answer your question?

```
factor = FactorInteger[1337]
```

> {{7, 1}, {191, 1}}

```
Times @@ (#[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ factor)
```

> 1337

Answer (score 1):

You can try using NextPrime:
`NextPrime[1337, -1]`